# Clean dde session in Python

Tags: python, dde

In a python script, I'm able to open a working dde session:

```
import win32ui
import dde 
server = dde.CreateServer() 
server.Create('MyServer') 
ch = dde.CreateConversation(server)
ch.ConnectTo('ExternalProgram','calculation')
```

Then, in the same script, I need to correctly close and "clean" that session, because I want to run again the same script in a second moment.

Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to close the dde session. Also after using server.Destroy() or server.Shutdown(), I still get an error when I try to create a new server and new conversation running the same script:

```
error: ConnectTo failed
```

Can you help? Thanks

My Python version:
'2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2014, 15:12:11) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]'
Running Windows 10, but problem was present also in Win 8.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this? I have a similar need.

Comment: No, nobody ever answered to my question.. :(

Comment: server.Destroy() seems to work for me.  I wonder what the difference is.